# List contents of multiple jar files

Tags: java, linux, shell, jar

I am searching for a .class file inside a bunch of jars.

```
jar tf abc.jar
```

works for one file. I tried

```
find -name "*.jar" | xargs jar tf
```

prints nothing. The only solution I can think of, is unzip all, then search. Is there a better way? I'm on LUnix.

**Edit**:
When scanning many jars, it is useful to print the jar file name along with the class. This method works well:

```
find . | grep jar$ | while read fname; do jar tf $fname | grep SchemaBuilder && echo $fname; done
```

Sample output produced:

```
  1572 Wed Jul 25 10:20:18 EDT 2007 org/apache/ws/commons/schema/SchemaBuilder$1.class
  1718 Wed Jul 25 10:20:18 EDT 2007 org/apache/ws/commons/schema/SchemaBuilder$2.class
 42607 Wed Jul 25 10:20:18 EDT 2007 org/apache/ws/commons/schema/SchemaBuilder.class
./XmlSchema-1.3.2.jar
  1572 Wed Jul 25 10:20:18 EDT 2007 org/apache/ws/commons/schema/SchemaBuilder$1.class
  1718 Wed Jul 25 10:20:18 EDT 2007 org/apache/ws/commons/schema/SchemaBuilder$2.class
 42607 Wed Jul 25 10:20:18 EDT 2007 org/apache/ws/commons/schema/SchemaBuilder.class
./XmlSchema.jar
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to pass `-n 1` to `xargs` to force it to run a separate `jar` command for each filename that it gets from `find`:

```
find -name "*.jar" | xargs -n 1 jar tf
```

Otherwise `xargs`'s command line looks like `jar tf file1.jar file2.jar...`, which has a different meaning to what is intended.

A useful debugging technique is to stick `echo` before the command to be run by `xargs`:

```
find -name "*.jar" | xargs echo jar tf
```

This would print out the full `jar` command instead of executing it, so that you can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Excellent tip with the "echo"

Comment: can you please modify command find -name "*.jar" | xargs -n 1 jar tf to show which file's contents are being show?

Comment: @AbhijitGaikwad I believe I have achieved which you and i wanted with this command
for i in $(ls -t $(find . -name '*.jar')); do echo $i && jar tf $i; done

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar situation where I need to search for a class in a list of jar files present in a directory. Also I wanted to know from which jar file the class belongs to. I used this below code snippet(shell script) and found out to be helpful. Below script will list down the jar files that contains the class to be searched.

```
#!/bin/sh
LOOK_FOR="codehaus/xfire/spring"
for i in `find . -name "*jar"`
do
  echo "Looking in $i ..."
  jar tvf $i | grep $LOOK_FOR > /dev/null
  if [ $? == 0 ]
  then
    echo "==> Found \"$LOOK_FOR\" in $i"
  fi
done
```

Shell script taken from : 
http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/shell-script-search-search-multiple-jar-files-class-pattern

Comment: Please try to add more context, not only post a link, since it may go stale in the future.

Comment: thanks for your inputs piet.t@ and mjuarez@. Updated my answer accordingly. feel free to provide your inputs. thanks!

Comment: Wonder why it's so slow?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `-exec` option of find

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec jar tf {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use in Cygwin. It supports section headers per jar file as requested above.

```
find . -name "*.jar" \
 -exec echo ======\ {}\ ====== \; \
 -exec /c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/jar.exe tf {} \; | less
```

For *nix, drop the ".exe":

```
find . -name "*.jar" \
 -exec echo ======\ {}\ ====== \; \
 -exec jar tf {} \; | less
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use unzip which is more faster than jar (-l option to print zip content).

For instance, a small script that does roughly what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(find . -name "*.jar")
do
    if [ -f $i ]
then
    echo $i
    unzip -l $i | grep $*
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the necessity for using exec, this worked for me in Cygwin on Windows:

```
find . -name "*.jar" | while read jarfile; do unzip -l $jarfile | fgrep "foo" ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Find jar files and get all classes and members saved on a txt.

```
(for j in $(find -name '*.jar');do echo "--$j --";jar tf $j | grep .class | sed 's#/#.#g' | sed 's/.class/ /g' | xargs -n 1 javap -classpath  $j ; done;) >> classes.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you coming to this question and you need to extract all jar files in a windows environment, navigate to the directory where you have saved all the jar files and save a batch file with the following content:

```
for /r %%f in (*) do jar -xvf %%f
```

By running the batch file, it will extract each jar file in the directory. The only thing here is that it will extract in the same directory where the jar file is.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Eclipse, you can create a project and add all jars. You will then be able to find a class in any of the jars.